# Testing without simulator using xctool

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode-storyboard, xctool

I'm trying to run unit tests without the simulator using **xctool**. I set the 'Host Application' to None in the test target's General tab, following the directions from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432762/3354041) .

When I run `xctool -project MyProject.xcodeproj/ -scheme MyProject test` I get this error.

```
<unknown>:0: failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException",
"Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle 
</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/
Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin> (loaded)"
```

I made sure that Main.storyboard is a member of the test target. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248913/cant-access-the-storyboard-from-senteskingkit) helped.

My test case set up method initialized the storyboard like this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:DEVMainStoryboardName 
bundle:nil];
```

Problem was passing nil to the bundle parameter, that uses the main bundle which is not what is used in the test target -- so you have to specify that you want to use the test bundle by writing

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:DEVMainStoryboardName 
bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
```

Then don't forget to include the storyboard as a member of the target.